# Why does it not return UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8

I want to get the title of some UTF-8 sites. I got them but when I want to use them (in main work as ajax response) here, for example, echo the contents, the browser is set to UTF-8 but it does not show correctly, where is the problem?

**---------------update----------------------**
I test all below solution but not work correctly in below webistes
It not return utf-8 for me in below wesites

http://roozannews.ir/detail/News/1553
http://asiaepress.com/detail/News/2226
http://www.hemayatonline.ir/detail/News/377
http://ecobourse.ir/detail/News/2308

**--------------------end of update------------------**

```
     $url='http://farhangipress.ir/detail/News/6753';
    $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

    if ($html) {
//parsing begins here:
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $title=iconv(mb_detect_encoding($title, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $title);
        echo $title;
        .....
```

my file_get_contents_curl is :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    //checking mime types
    if (strstr($info, 'text/html')) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

First I tried:

```
 $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo $title;
```

But is was not working correctly.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `iconv` conversion? Detecting and converting encodings does not work well by definition.

Comment: @deceze you mean I try $title=mb_detect_encoding($title, mb_detect_order(), true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only feeding a string of HTML to DOMDocument - it has no idea what charset it is in.

There are a couple of ways a website can tell you what charset it's content is in:

- HTTP Content-Type header, e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
- HTML Content-Type meta-attr, e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

The first (HTTP header) is quite useless in this context: `file_get_contents_curl()` reads the data from the server and returns only the content, which it feeds to DOMDocument - DOMDocument has no idea what tha HTTP headers were.

The second will be correctly tell DOMDocument what charset the content is in, but will likely not be present in a lot of websites (since HTTP header will already tell a browser what charset the content is in, there is often no need to also add the HTML meta-attr)

So in order to actually let DOMDocument know of the charset the HTML is in, you can either:

- make sure the meta-attribute is set in the HTML
- add an XML prolog defining the charset to your content: `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>`
- use `mb_convert_encoding()`

So this should work:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = '<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

or

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding( $html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' );
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

or even this should work, but strictly speaking, meta tags belong in `<head>` (not in front of the entire HTML)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $html;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Note that passing the encoding as 2nd argument to DOMDocument's constructor will **not** work:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); // won't work!
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the header on top and you are good to go.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
$url='http://farhangipress.ir/detail/News/6755';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
```

### The **`cURL`** way...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
   }

$url='http://farhangipress.ir/detail/News/6753';
echo $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

[image]

Comment: please look at the my file_get_contents_curl funtion, when I use this method u mentioned , (add header) , it retrun me empty html :(

Comment: Why do you need `cURL` here ? Won't `file_get_contents` suffice ?

Comment: the sites remove it, test something else like `http://farhangipress.ir/detail/News/6753`

Comment: Does not matter curl or file_get_content, before new domDocument this is ok, i have this problem when i want get news from joomla farsi rss, when php convert it to object in domDocument convert it to ANSI encoding by default you must use `mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')`

Answer (score 2):

try this i test in farsi RSS reader and give feed back

```
 new DOMDocument('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"');
 $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I try this , but to see any changes in results :(

Answer (score 0):

finally I found my solution

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl($url);
$html=mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```